# Missing data in a report in Report Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When I run a report in my Report Server, it will provide the results, but it is missing several rows and random cells of data. When I run this report in SSRS, it contains all the data. I did change the DataElementOutput on the report from "Auto" to "Output" and redeployed the report, but I still run into the same issue. Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Compare a profiler trace of running it in the two environments and make sure both are sending the same calls to your database.

Comment: Any time you have a data issue comparing Report Server to results from the same report in Visual Studio BIDS, you should try deleting the **.rdl.data** file in your report folder to be sure that BIDS isn't using cached data.

Comment: I usually just delete the .rdl file from the server and redeploy.